# error #1005 - Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Intento crear una tabla que hace referencia a una llave foránea que he creado anteriormente la sentencia de mi instrucción va así:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS opcion(
    id_opcion varchar(21) not null,
    id_pregunta varchar (21)not null,
    primary key(id_opcion),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_pregunta) REFERENCES pregunta(id_pregunta),
    c_opcion varchar(255)
);
```

y el resultado que me indica es este

> 1005 - Can't create table 'encuestas_egresados.opcion' (errno: 150) (Detalles...)

A continuación les muestro una imagen donde se muestra la estructura de la tabla a la que hago referencia.

> nota anteriormente en la tabla utilizaba el atributo id en vez de id_pregunta no se si eso interfiera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: id_pregunta en la tabla pregunta esta indexada?? si no lo esta, puede ser ese el error.

Comment: La tabla pregunta es InnoDB?

Comment: Lo más probable es que no tengas una llave primaria creada en la tabla `pregunta`, o haces referencia a la columna que no es llave

Comment: esto es lo que me devuelve en el estado del InnoDB

Comment: InnoDB  Documentación

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Reserva de búfers | Estado del InnoDB ]

Comment: Intentaste darle un nombre diferente a la columna id_pregunta en tu tabla opcion?